# Pandas - Using column of lists as key to create additional column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe "df1" with a column "team_name". I have a different dataframe "df2" with two columns: "city" as a string, and "teams" as a list. I want to create a new column in df1 called "team_city", where the city name is found in df2's "city" column by finding the row whose list in the "teams" column contains "team_name."

(example: if "team_name" equals "Denver", I want to find the row in df2 where "teams" contains "Denver", and then extract the value of "team_city" in that row.)

I'm currently applying a function over the "team_name" column in df1 that looks like the following:

```
def get_city(name):
df2 = clean_cities()
for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    if name in row['teams']:
        return row['city']
```

I'm curious if there's a better way to do this. Does a vectorized function exist within pandas that can accomplish this?

Comment: Hi. It's always much easier if we can see some sample of your data and output you expect. Then you don't need to write too much and get the response quicker.

Comment: df2 explode then df1 merge

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using your `get_city` function, explode your `df2['teams']` sublist into multiple rows:

```
team_df = df2.explode(column='teams')
```

Then, in your original data frame, let's call it `df`:

```
df['city'] = df['name'].map(team_df.set_index('teams')['city'])
```

This assumes that there is a unique team name. If there isn't, this won't work. If that is the case, I would then try merging: `df.merge(team_df[['teams', 'city']], left_on=$TEAM_NAME_COLUMN, right_on='teams', how='left')`. You may need to do further reduction.